# Is it possible to center text in a div both vertically and horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I mean by not using any other tags...just one tag and the CSS for it.

So

http://jsfiddle.net/EqTsu/

```
<style>
  #test{
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      text-align: center;
      border: solid 1px #ff0000;
    }
</style>

<div id='test'>foo</div>
```

needs what to center vertically?

**Per Answers Below**

It needs

```
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a sort of hack-ish work-around where you give the `<div>` the `display: table-cell;` property and then the `vertical-align: middle;` property, yes.

So the complete CSS would be:

```
#test{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 1px #ff0000;
}
```

Also, external stylesheets are your friends.

Comment: Does not seem like a hack...just a display option per http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: Based on the [Can I Use Report](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table), yes. It's hack-ish because it's changing the `<div>` (whose only native feature is `display: block;`) to have a different display.

Comment: What do you mean by "native feature"...I looked here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp, but saw nothing about native features....

Comment: `<div>` and `<span>` are basically featureless tags used only for styling; they have no inherent meaning. The only difference between them is that `<div>` is `display: block;` and `<span>` is `display: inline;`. Maybe it's just me being over-zealous about things, but "don't use tables, use a `<div>` that pretends to be a table!" seems like a hack-ish work-around to me..

Comment: 'default' === 'native' .....you are just changing the default value...it is not normal...but not a hack....do you know of an element that has a default setting of display: table-cell?

Comment: `<th>` and `<td>` are the only elements that have it by default.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a jsFiddle using your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/EqTsu/2/

Adding `display: table-cell;` will cause the element to be treated like a cell in a table, which then enables you to use the table formatting CSS `vertical-align: middle;`.

Comment: I like your logo...I have a site called arcmarks.com(not up yet) that uses that style...or that from...different colors though....arcs

Answer (score 1):

[Understanding vertical-align, or "How (Not) To Vertically Center Content"](http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html)

Comment: Perhaps a more useful link, considering the age of that one: [Everything you know about CSS is wrong](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/everything_you_know_about_CSS_Is_wrong/). Don't much care for the title, but I would not recommend either of those ways.